# Workflow to Auto start 2 workflows one after the other

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-manager

I have two workflows that need to start one after the other. How would I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Have a look to this Action **Start Another Worflow**
http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20Another%20Workflow

Option 2:
When a column field change then start another workflow

Option 3:
Workflow Organiser
http://sp2010adminpack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Workflow%20Organizer&FocusElement=Comment